# SQL server casting string to integer checking value before casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a table with a field named `MINIMUM_AGE`.  The values stored in this field are of type `nvarchar`:

```
17 years
54 years 
N/A
65 years
```

I would like to apply a WHERE clause on the column to check for a certain age range.  To do that I need to parse out the age from the field values.

So, I think I need to select the first two characters, then cast them into an integer.  Also, some fields may not contain numbers for the first two characters.  Some may simply be `N/A`.  So, I will need to check for that before casting.

Can someone explain how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28b16/3/0) that demonstrates the below query:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN MINIMUM_AGE <> 'N/A' 
  THEN CAST(LEFT(MINIMUM_AGE, 2) AS int)
  ELSE 0
  END
FROM MyTable
```

Note: the CASE expression can only return one data type.  So, in the example above if the `MINIMUM_AGE` is `N/A` then it returns `0`.

If you would rather have it return ***null***, then use the following:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN MINIMUM_AGE <> 'N/A' 
  THEN CAST(LEFT(MINIMUM_AGE, 2) AS int)
  END
FROM MyTable
```