# SQL Server select query to retrieve quoted text

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table named Test, where columns are as follows..

```
AC_ID varchar(50)
Region varchar(50)
Areas varchar(50)
Month varchar(50)
Revenue money
Margin money
```

and the entries of varchar columns are in quotes like, `Acc_ID is '100'`, `Region is' XYZ'`, `Areas is 'ABC'` etc...

I want a select statement to query total revenue of a particular region in a particular month. 
I am using SQL Server

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: well, the title has this ***query to retrieve quoted text*** and the question content has this ***query total revenue of a particular region in a particular month***, so what is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server casting string to integer checking value before casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253478/sql-server-casting-string-to-integer-checking-value-before-casting)

Comment: What you should be looking for is how to cast a varchar

Comment: Sorry for the wrong title I am an armature user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS "Total Revenue"
FROM Test
WHERE Region = 'Some Text'
and Month = 'Some Text'
GROUP BY Region, Month;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: How do I pass a where clause?

Comment: Even if I write a simple select stament like  select revenue from testing where region = 'xyz', it is not showing any value.

Comment: i think your table name is test not testing.

Comment: Oh sorry! here I typed it wrong,  I did queried from test. No syntax error its throwing. But still I am not getting any value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  Region, Month, SUM(ISNULL([Revenue money],'0'))
From    Test
Where   Region = 'RegionXYZ'
            and month = 'Month123'
Group by Region, Month
```

Might be worth considering storing the month in a datetime column, or have a year column too. Otherwise you will be summing up the Revenue Money for the month for all the years of data you have in your table.

Comment: The is null function requires 2 arguments

Comment: No it doesn't, ISNULL is stating if the value is NULL, [Revenue Table] is telling it which column to use and the '0' is telling it to replace NULL values with a 0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: I understand that but when i am runing your query in my DB it's showing me that error.

Comment: have you copied it exactly as I have written it, with square brackets around the column name? (it has white space in the column name so needs the brackets)

Comment: This time qury runed but  still not getting any result ... nothing

Comment: Run a select on the table with just the region in your where clause, do you have any results for that month for that region? or do it the other way, run a select * specifying the month, does that region appear?

Comment: No,  nothing no result . I queried select * from  test where region = 'xyz'

Comment: That's why then, if the data doesn't exist it isn't going to be returned in the query result. Do a select * from test, pick any row and use it's region and month. Use them in your query and see if it returns. If it does your query is done, it works. Are you wanting to get the region and month returned even if there is no data?

Comment: Yes i tried with an existing record only. Anyway thanks a lot for trying to help if i come up with a solution I'll let you know..

Comment: Are you trying to get the region and month returned even when there's no result?

Comment: solved it! The objective was to pass the value of region column in where clause,  i was having difficulty because the values were characters, already in quotes  even the like statement wasn't working...  i deleted the database, created a new database  and transfered the datas from that table and runned the like statment and it worked like a charm!